# Parsing json error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object:

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse a large json file which contains a bunch of cities (the following is the first two cities in the file):

```
  [
  {
    "id": 707860,
    "name": "Hurzuf",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 34.283333,
      "lat": 44.549999
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 519188,
    "name": "Novinki",
    "country": "RU",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 37.666668,
      "lat": 55.683334
    }
  } ]
```

I want to get the IDs of cities whose "name" value matches a String:

```
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    JsonElement jsontree = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Users/kevin/Eclipse-workspace-new/kevinzhou_CSCI201_assignment3/WebContent/city.list.json"));
    JsonElement je = jsontree.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonArray ja = je.getAsJsonArray();
    for (Object o : ja)
    {
        JsonObject city = (JsonObject) o;
        if(cityName == city.get("name").getAsString())
        {
            System.out.println(city.get("id").getAsString());
        }
    }
```

However, I am getting the following error : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object:`
and then it spits out the entire file after the colon.

Comment: you are getting an array as an object

Comment: And which JSON parser would this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change to

```
// JsonElement je = jsontree.getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray ja = jsontree.getAsJsonArray();
```

as it contains an Array at the top level

Answer (score 3):

Try below given code to handle both condition

```
if (jsontree instanceof JsonObject) {
    JsonObject  jobject = new JsonObject(jsontree .getAsJsonObject());
 } else if (jsontree instanceof JsonArray) {
    JsonArray  jarray =  new JsonArray(jsontree .getAsJsonArray());
 }
```